# Using orderby before group by from two different tables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following query

```
SELECT 
  quote.id , 
    quote.createdAt,
    status.status AS 'Status'

FROM
     quote
       JOIN
    quotelog ON quotelog.quote = quote.id
        JOIN
    status ON status.id = quotelog.status
```

the relationship between quote and quotelog is one to many, what I want is to display the latest quotelog for the quote.

Both quote and quotelog have created_at, I'm displaying here the creation date of the quote.

the result While each quote have multiple status, I only want to get the latest one for each quote

```
id  createdAt   Status
1   07-12-15 6:14   newQuote
2   07-12-15 6:40   newQuote
2   07-12-15 6:40   quoteCancelled
3   07-12-15 7:21   newQuote
3   07-12-15 7:21   quotePaused
4   07-12-15 8:17   newQuote
4   07-12-15 8:17   quoteCompleted
```

with adding group by quote.id I get this

```
id  createdAt   Status
1   07-12-15 6:14   newQuote
2   07-12-15 6:40   newQuote
3   07-12-15 7:21   newQuote
4   07-12-15 8:17   newQuote
```

I want it to look like this

```
id  createdAt   Status
1   07-12-15 6:14   newQuote
2   07-12-15 6:40   quoteCancelled
3   07-12-15 7:21   quotePaused
4   07-12-15 8:17   quoteCompleted
```

so what I need is to order by qoutelog.createdAt before grouping by quote.id

I found answers in stackoverflow but they only deal with one table either by using HAVING after group by or self join sub query result that contain order by
or using  Row_number() which Mysql doesn't support

Comment: First, if you're not already, store dates using a proper date data type.

Comment: I'm using datetime, isn't it a proper data type ?

Comment: It is, so that's all right then

Comment: Please provide sample data.  It doesn't make sense to me that `created_at` comes from `quote` if there is a one-to-many relationship to `quote_log`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff both quote and quote_log have created_at column, what I'm displaying is the created_at of the quote, like my report display the creation date of the quote and it's latest status

Comment: @user1493376 . . . That is what my answer does.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this can be handled with `MAX()` function :

```
SELECT 
  quote.id , 
    quote.createdAt,
    max(status.status) AS 'Status'

FROM
     quote
       JOIN
    quotelog ON quotelog.quote = quote.id
        JOIN
    status ON status.id = quotelog.status
GROUP BY quote.id
```

Since 'q' is bigger then 'n' , it will select quote..* first.

If for each id there can be multiple(more then 2) statuses, including a few with quote...* then you have to specify the logic you want to select them and I'll adjust the query.

Comment: Looks can be deceiving

Comment: @Strawberry DATES are the same, ID's are the same, only difference is status. I shouldn't get downvote for lack of information in the OP question, and besides you don't even know if thats not what he needs

Comment: You've correctly answered this question elsewhere, so odd that you should get it wrong here. The dv seems fair to me.

Comment: When OP posts data sample like this, where each group has the exact same dates(note that each group have different dates) I assumed this is not a typo and wanted to save him the unnecessary `EXISTS()` . I wasn't wrong, -IF- this answer is incorrect, then its becuase I misunderstood his requirment. @Strawberry

Comment: @sagi my bad , I forget to mention that quotelog have createdAt, my query is little more complex than mentioned in the post, I had to remove stuff so  SO users can focus on my main problem and I forget to mention createdAt

Answer (score 0):

You do not use `group by` for this operation.  You want to select an entire *row*, not summarize columns within a row.

The approach uses some logic for selecting the row.  I am guessing that `created_at` really comes form `quote_log` and not `quote`.

Here is one method:

```
SELECT q.id, q.createdAt, s.status
FROM quote q JOIN
     quotelog ql
     ON ql.quote = q.id JOIN
     status s
     ON s.id = ql.status
WHERE ql.created_at = (SELECT MAX(ql2.created_at)
                       FROM quotelog ql2
                       WHERE ql2.id = ql.id
                      );
```

Comment: it return the same result as sample data I provided in OP but sub query is needed so thanks for the idea

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to get the max(createdAt) by quotelog is to use a subquery to return the max date and then join that  tables with max date

```
SELECT quote.id 
     , quote.createdAt
     , status.status 
  FROM quote
INNER
  JOIN ( SELECT quote
              , MAX(createdAt) AS latest
           FROM quotelog 
         GROUP
             BY quote ) AS q
    ON q.quote = quote.id
INNER
  JOIN quotelog
    ON quotelog.quote = q.quote
   AND quotelog.createdAt = q.latest
INNER
  JOIN status 
    ON status.id = quotelog.status
```